# django how to Dynamic get TemplateView in url

Tags: regex, django

I have the following urls

```
url(r'^view/1$', View1.as_view(), name='view'),
url(r'^view/2$', View2.as_view(), name='view'),
url(r'^view/3$', View3.as_view(), name='view'),
```

and the views views

```
class View1(TemplateView):
    pass

class View2(TemplateView):
    pass

class View3(TemplateView):
    pass
```

and my question is how to Dynamically get TemplateView based on a regular expression

i.e., I want something like
    url(r'^view/(number)$', View(number).as_view(), name='view'),

Answer (score 0):

The django documentation is quite good. Please search there before asking a question. Here's a link from the Django Book. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation

What you want is a regular expression for digits.

So `url(r'^view/(\d+)$', view)`

And then your view must take a parameter.

Something like:

```
def view(request, number):
    if number == 1:
        #do first thing
    elif number == 2:
        #do second thing
    #etc...
```

Of course, the more logical way to use something like this, would be for the number to correspond to some data (say, the pk of an object stored in your database). Remember, it's best to have your urls mean something. So if there are three urls that are doing something totally different, maybe they should look almost identical, with only a number to differentiate them.

Comment: my view is class view—— TemplateView so with TemplateView how to do it thanks

Comment: my quesiton is how to use class-based view——TemplateView, not function view