# django how to create TemplateView instance with code

Tags: django, django-views

I have a function view,and i want to create a TemplateView instance in this function,such as

```
def MyView(request):
    #view =TemplateView(request)
    #view =TemplateView.as_view()
    #view =TemplateView.as_view()(request)
    return view
```

but,all of them is wrong. How do I create the view?

urls:

```
mysite/widget1/
mysite/widget2/
mysite/widget3/
```

views:

```
class BaseWidgetTemplateView(TemplateView):
    pass
class Widget1View(BaseWidgetTemplateView):
    pass
class Widget2View(BaseWidgetTemplateView):
    pass
class Widget3View(BaseWidgetTemplateView):
    pass
```

the request to pass to the function view and pass to the TemplateView is diffent object type
the request which pass to the function is

```
module 'django.http.request
```

and the request in TemplateView is

```
WSGIRequest
```

Comment: you already asked this question, so please explain what you need to do. why whould you want to do something like that instead of going with the standard cbv method? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Comment: yes but that question is closed.what i want to do is i have some urls such like data/1/、data/2/、data/3。。。and data/1/ use TemplateView1,data/2/ user TemplateView2....Dynamic get TemplateView in url. so my methon is define a function view and in this view to call the diffrent TemplateView

Comment: the question is in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082516/django-how-to-dynamic-get-templateview-in-url

Comment: If it was closed, it's probably because it's not an appropriate question. Tell us _what_ you want to do, and maybe we can help. It very well may be that a TemplateView isn't the best way to do whatever you need.

Comment: so how to do it with TemplateView

Comment: why not simply define 3 views and 3 urls? if you need common functionalities, subclassing is there to help. why whould you want to recreate something that django does for you anyway?

Comment: yes i have some similar widgets ,so the TemplateView1、 TemplateView2 and TemplateView3 is inherit from BaseWidgetTemplateView。but each of the widget is to use diffrent TemplateView. widget1 use TemplateView1,widget2 use TemplateView2....

Comment: what? show some real code please, not just that piece.

Comment: i just want to Dynamic call TemplateView according to the url. example   mysite/widget1/ use TemplateView1. mysite/widget2/ use TemplateView2. mysite/widget3/ use TemplateView3... ....

Answer (score 0):

Again, [class based views page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) on Django docs:

```
(r'mysite/widget1/', Widget1View.as_view()),
(r'mysite/widget2/', Widget2View.as_view()),
(r'mysite/widget3/', Widget2View.as_view()),
```

this is all you need to define in your `urls.py` file.

Comment: ye i know this way . but is there some way to Dynamic call the templateview? such as (r'mysite/widget(?P<id>\d+)/', Widget(the id)View.as_view()),

Comment: if you need to do something like that, you may need to reconsider your design (as in: fetch the <id> in one view and do what you need there, rather than defining a different view for each type of id you need)

Comment: yes i have considered it.... in the get_context_data it is fine to use your method. but in the post_context_data is not good. so this is the reason to use different views. thanks all of you

Comment: ??? what's post_context_data? You can fetch the same `<id>` param in your redefined post method, since you have the request available. Really, check out the docs on class based views

Comment: the TemplateView has get_context_data to the get methond request, i added post_context_data to the TemplateView. each widget view has diffrent form to edit,so i have to edit the form in different post_context_data.

Comment: well, you handle the `post` call inside your own `post` method. you can also edit `form_valid` method to edit and display the correct form. docs tell all, if you just read them

Comment: all the form element are in mysql. each widget is alone and dynamically creation and save. i didn't use django's form

Comment: by the way, if i want to create TemplateView instance with code. how to do it? such as my question